# How can work be done during collisions?

Tags: energy, momentum, work, collision

Consider a collision between two material points, with no external forces acting on the system.

Linear and angular momentum of the system are always conserved, while the kinetic energy of the system is conserved only if internal forces acting in the collision are conservative. This last point is not clear to me.

During the time interval $\tau$ of the collision we assume that the position of the two particles does not change, i.e. $\vec{r_1}=\vec{r_2}=\vec{r}$. But the velocity of each particle (precisely its momentum) does change during the collision, and, from WE theorem, that means that **a work** is done on each particle, equal to the change in kinetic energy of the particle itself.

Nevertheless work is force times a displacement, and we said that the position of particle is constant during the collision. So where is the displacement?

Supposing that I didn't made mistake in this reasoning, if there is no displacement there is no work, so how can the velocity of particles change actually?

And then if there is no work how can kinetic energy of each particle (and of the system) not be conserved?

Edit: with "material point" I mean [point particle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Point_particle)

Comment: What is a "material point"? All bodies that collide have some kind of spatial extent, and they can deform. You can't speak about "work being done" when two points collide because physical objects are not points.

Comment: Another way of thinking about this is to ask: how (classically) would you arrange for two point particles to collide?  What proportion of the state space of the system has such collisions?

Comment: You've intentionally hidden things in assumptions of infinities (particles either don't interact or come to an instant dead stop, point particles, etc), and then you are surprised that the physics is hidden and not intuitive?

Answer (score 2):

The collision doesn't happen at a single point in space - rather the colliding objects exert a forces on each other over a distance as they approach and the recede.  Consider a tennis ball hitting a racket - the ball and the strings of the racket deform and we get an increasing elastic restoring forces until the two objects at at their closest approach. Then, the forces get smaller again as they objects return to their original shape and drop to zero once they aren't touching.

You could consider a collision between electrons in the same way.  There is an increasing electric force between them as they go into the collision and decreasing as the come out of the collision.  In the case of the electrons though, there isn't a clear cut beginning and ending since the forces between them aren't zero at any distance.

Answer (score 1):

Work (or energy) is transferred from one particle to another, but the net effect is no change overall.

How?

Consider a collision force acting between two particles over a small time frame. During that time frame the particles move, and the work done on one particle is ${\rm d}W_1 = \boldsymbol{F} \cdot {\rm d}\boldsymbol{x}_1$. Since an equal and opposite force *acting on the same line of action* acts on the other particle the work for the other particle is ${\rm d}W_2 = -\boldsymbol{F} \cdot {\rm d}\boldsymbol{x}_2$. The stipulation here is that the two particles move together for the duration of the contact (and hence their displacements ${\rm d}\boldsymbol{x}_1={\rm d}\boldsymbol{x}_2$ are the same). The net result is ${\rm d}W_1 + {\rm d}W_2 = 0$.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I think I got the point but how is this related to the **conservation** of kinetic energy? I mean Newton third law (which you used) is valid for **any** force (conservative or not). The sum of the works should then be zero indipendently from the fact that the force is conservative or not. Nevertheless if non conservative force act kinetic energy is not conserved. How can that be?